# Sefira Upcoming Event?

Tags: discussion, events

(Again with the Upcoming Events requests. What is up with this guy?)

On the sidebar, should there be a Sefira upcoming (ongoing) event, for questions tagged [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty soon, the Shavuot one is slated to start running. Rather than crowd the sidebar too much, how about one event for Omer and Shavuot (to start today)?

Please edit this post to list tags that should be included in a combined link.

- [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer)
- [shavuos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shavuos)
- [lag-ba-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag-ba-omer)

I've implemented this with the three tags listed above. I'm open to adding additional tags.

Comment: I'm not sure that Lag Ba'omer should be included, here. If I understand this Q, it seems to focus only on the entire Sefira period, of which Shavu'ot, only would make sense as that is the end-point of Sefira, Lag Ba'omer is a "holiday". If you include Lag Ba'omer, it seems you would have to include Yom Hazikaron , Yom Ha'atzma'ut, Pesach Sheni, Yom Hasho'ah, 3 Days Hagbalah, etc. Why would you limit it to just Lag Ba'omer?

Comment: @DanF, I think it'd get too crowded to add separate events for all of the relatively-minor holidays during this period, but there's little harm in adding seasonally-appropriate tags to this seasonal event. If you have other tags you think would be similarly relevant, please feel free to [edit] them in here, and if practical, I'll add them to the event's link.